# The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid in flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to achieve Firebase phone auth in my flutter application, I've used packages : [Firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) And [Firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) , here is the code i've use d:

```dart
          FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
          _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber: '+2$mobile',
              timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
              verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCredential){
                var _credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: actualCode, smsCode: smsCodeController.text);
                _auth.signInWithCredential(_credential).then((UserCredential result) async {
                  pr.hide();
                  setState(() {
                    status = 'Authentication successful';
                  });
//The rest of my success code
                }).catchError((e){
                  print(e);
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Welcome()),
                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);                
};
              },
              verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException  authException){
                print(authException.message);
              },
              codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
                setState(() {
                  actualCode = verificationId;
                  status = 'Code sent';
                });
              },
              codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId){
                verificationId = verificationId;
                print(verificationId);
                setState(() {
                  status = 'Auto retrieval timeout';
                });
              },
              );
```

But i always get this error :

```dart
[firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid.
```

Any help ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this line exists:

```dart
var _credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: actualCode, smsCode: smsCodeController.text);
```

You already get a credential from the parameter `authCredential` so just sign in with that since it's valid.

The way the `verifyPhoneNumber` method works in `FirebaseAuth` is as follows:

- `verificationFailed`: callback for any errors thrown while verifying
- `verificationCompleted`: if no sms code was needed to verify (google knows it's a valid number)
- `codeSent`: triggered when a code was sent, this is the function that you would have the user enter the sms code and create an `AuthCredential` from it with the provided `verificationId` and the sms code.

Comment: This is not the case !!! VerificationId is created whenever the request to authentication is made. And it is uniques every time

Comment: @AliYarKhan how to avoid this error ? any help

Comment: @RajendraAVerma i haven't found any solution :-/

Comment: Make sure you passed the real verificationId value while your app is  on background when reading sms code.                                                                                                      
In my case, I make verificationId as global variable after codeSent callback as _verificationId and use it in signInWithSmsCode(String smsCode) as follows.                                                                                                     
 AuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(smsCode: smsCode, verificationId: _verificationId); and it is working.