# firebase_auth/invalid-verification-is error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

[Error authentication failed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3wPi.jpg)

Facing the error to follow this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth to authenticate from native device  i configure all configuration of this.
My firebase code for sending code on phone number is:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                            phoneNumber: '+92$phone',
                            timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
                            verificationCompleted:
                                (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
                            verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
                            codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
                              MyPhone.verify = verificationId;
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'otp');
                            },
                            codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
                          );
```

and for verification is following code

```
PhoneAuthCredential credential =
                                PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                                    verificationId: MyPhone.verify, smsCode: code);
                            await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                .signInWithCredential(credential);
    Kindly someone help me out to resolve error.
```

Error showed "[firebase_auth/invalid-verification-is] The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669224/the-verification-id-used-to-create-the-phone-auth-credential-is-invalid-in-flutt Check out this,is this answer your question

Comment: Nothing help me out anyone can have another solution?

Comment: I already check above answer but this did not resolve the the error @Flutty dev.